# How do I install the 'no-ip' package on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The noip2 (no-ip.com) package was deleted from the repository, now what?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184704/the-noip2-no-ip-com-package-was-deleted-from-the-repository-now-what)

I just Installed Ubuntu server 12.04 and I want to install `no-ip`.

I ran as root: `sudo apt-get install noip2`

And I got this:

```
root@topcat:/var# sudo apt-get install noip2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package noip2
```

I also tried with this command:

```
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

But I got this error:

```
wget: unable to resolve host address 'www.no-ip.com'`
```

Can someone help me? I am new to Ubuntu.