# No-Ip 2 Install in Ubuntu 12.04 No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am trying to install noip2. After following these instructions I have reached a roadblock.

[How do I install the 'no-ip' package on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148813/how-do-i-install-the-no-ip-package-on-12-04)

When I type in make I receive the following error.

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed to the package directory? Use `cd`:

```
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar -xzvf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
cd noip-2.1.9-1
make
sudo make install
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be [ddclient](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS). It works fine in my setup with the no-ip service and it is in the Ubuntu repositories.